# Would a size-specific, electrophoresis-based RNA quantification kit work for ssDNA as well?

Tags: molecular-biology, dna, pcr

I'm using a custom library of ssDNA oligos to test the performance of some qPCR assays with mismatched bases in various primer and probe regions, and I'm trying to come up with a good way to verify whether or not my results are due to differences in assay performance or differences in the copy number of fully synthesized templates.

Basically, the fragments I was asked to order were only available with the most basic desalting purification protocol, which does not include any fragment size selection and can therefore include incomplete or degraded templates. After verifying quantifications with absorbance- and fluorescence-based methods, there's not enough of a difference to explain my qPCR results. But, again, this doesn't account for any potential differences in fragment length/completeness.

I have access to an instrument that provides size-specific quantification and integrity assessment based on electrophoretic separation. But the available DNA kits use SYBR Green I, which is really a dsDNA dye and only weakly interacts with ssDNA. They sell RNA quantification kits using SYBR Gold, a better choice for ssDNA, but when I called tech support to ask about ssDNA, I got the boilerplate response. They haven't tested their kits for that application so they can't recommend it or comment on whether or not it will provide good results.

So I'm just here asking if there's some difference in buffer or gel properties that would prevent ssDNA from properly running on an RNA-specific electrophoresis platform. I've looked up a few standard RNA gel electrophoresis protocols and they all seem similar enough to DNA gels, so I'm assuming the instrument's RNA kit would probably work for DNA as well. Just wanted to see if anyone on here had specific experience that might contradict that assessment.